# remove blue outline from uitabbaritem image

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have changed the   tabBar.selectedImageTintColor to my own purlple color however when the tabbar item is selected there is a bright blue line that surrounds the outside of the image which is now purple..

This looks fairly bad, so now I am trying to find a way to either remove it or change it to a better matching color.

However I don't know how to do it and am hoping someone can tell me.

This is the blue line I am talking about

[image]

This is how I changed the image selection color to purpule...

```
 myTabBar.selectedImageTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:49.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:98.0/255.0 alpha:0.95];
```

another example of the blue outline with tabbaricon scaled up

[image]

Comment: You can use a custom image for tab bar item.

Comment: yea, I am using a custom image but its still adding that funny blue outline.. I will do a screen shot.

Comment: Can you pls post some code you have used?

Comment: How you will set the custom image for tab bar? I have used the above code for tab bar default buttons and works fine.

Comment: **self.button1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1.png"];**

Comment: are you not getting a blue edging around your image?@Neptune

Comment: I had used the same code in my system. But it works fine. There is no blue edging. I thing there is a problem in your image.

Comment: hrmm.. nope still seems to be happening.. i have tried several icon providers icons and still getting that blue outline.

Comment: i am also getting the blue outline on my tabbarimage,how to remove that one?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 5, there are appearance methods that you can set.

Create your unselected and selected images exactly as you want them to appear and then `setFinishedSelectedImage:` `withFinishedUnselectedImage:` iOS will not apply any formatting to the images you provide through this method.

```
UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageWithName:@"my_finished_selected_image"];
UIImage *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageWithName:@"my_finished_unselected_image"];
[tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage];
```

Comment: This method works but it's deprecated now. Do you know the iOS 7 equivalent of this?